# iOS hybrid app - Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]iOS hybrid app - Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError

We are developing an iOS hybrid app.

1. We have index.html and using cordova phone gap we have packaged and bundled as an app.
2. We have also created a new key for google maps api.

After adding the new maps api it gives the error  Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError.

Since our app is a hybrid app we don't have a hosted url for Index.html

SO we have generated the Api Key for google Maps Javascript api using iOS bundle identifier.

Please help.

Comment: Even after changing to browser key instead of iOS key .. issue still exists. After adding the Browser key and have added * to allow all URL and waited for 5 mins. Still the Referer Not allowed Map error is thrown.

Comment: If you remove all entries, it should work (ie, remove *)

Answer (score 2):

It worked well after following these steps:

1. Edit API Key.
2. Under Application restrictions choose: HTTP referrers (web sites).
3. Under Accept requests from these HTTP referrers insert domain with character: *
4. Click Save.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use a **browser key** instead of an iOS key (the Maps Javascript API authorizes applications based on their referring domain).

Also note that file:// referers require a special config:

> file:// referers need a special representation to be added to the Key restriction. The "file:/" part should be replaced with "**file_url**" before being added to the Key restriction. For example, "file://path/to/" should be formatted as "**file_url**/path/to/*". After enabling file:// referers, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key-restrictions

Comment: I get this error even after adding * to the Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (websites)  text box.Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: file:///Users/karthikvasudevan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/61D384DB-CBB2-46BD-B859-8424A3FCDA72/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/547304FE-0320-414C-80CF-5C21F3F00CD0/MissionTravel%20QA.app/www/index.html

Comment: I just deleted all entries in the list of allowed referrers. No star entry, nothing. Then you get warned that your key can abused that way. Accept and save. I just wonder how to fix this case in hybrid apps to have your key protected? I can't find anything on Google Maps site. Does anybody know?

Comment: for iOS referrer url, the `ID` changes every time you compile the app, so its impossible to add the full URL:  ie: __file_url__//var/containers/Bundle/Application/22177042-7424-4B45-A25B-CFE8F0671BA6/myApp.app/www/index.html#/tab/map////  - I tried removing the unique compile ID and replace with a wildcard `*` but its not working:  __file_url__//var/containers/Bundle/Application/*/myApp.app/www/index.html#/tab/map//// - does anyone know a way around this?  Also, will this URL path be the same in the submitted version versus my the dev version I am compiling locally?

Answer (score 1):

Our Ionic app was using the places API, we resolved the RefererNotAllowedMapError error by:

1. Activating Maps javascript API and places API
2. Set application restrictions to None (referer)
3. Activated billing (step may not be required)
4. Regenerated API key and replace old key with new key value in the code base

Everything was fixed, probably after regenerating the API key.

If you wish to add a referrer for Ionic, you will need to add the URL shown in the error thrown by the maps api (replace `file://` with `__file_url__`)

[image: Regenerate places API key]